# Write a program that reads in a string and prints whether it

Tags: python, xcode

- contains only letter
- contains only uppercase letters
- contains only lowercase letters
- contains only digits
- contains only letters and digits
- starts with an uppercase letters
- ends with period

```html
words = input("Enter a Letter: ")
int_words = int(words)
if words.isupper() == words.islower():
    print("Contains only letters")
elif words.isupper() > words.islower():
    print("Contains only upper letters")
else:
    print("Contains only lower letters")
if int_words.isdigit():
    print("Contains only digits")
else:
    print("Contains Letters and Digits")
```

I'm not even halfway through my assignment and I get this error already. In the print("Contains only digits") I want it to be able to run on "Contains only digits" but it runs the "Contains Letters" and "Contains digits" together.
I also get this error

> "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'"
> I just want to convert the string into int so that I could only run the print("Contains only Digits")

I really need help. I'm a freshmen in coding so I'm really new into this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code sample I first evaluated if the string (words) was a digit, if it wasn't then I proceed to check if the string contained a digit by using a for loop, you can read more about for loops in [here][1] and [here][2] for the rest of the script I just evaluated if the any of the other conditions where met by using *is* and *is not* comparison statements, you can read more about it in [here][3] and then proceeded to print the desired output.

````py
words = input("Enter a Letter: ")
numbers = False
if not words.isdigit():
    for character in words:
        if character.isdigit():
            print("Contains Letters and Digits.")
            numbers = True
            break
if not words.isdigit() and words.islower() and not words.endswith(".") and not numbers:
    print("Contains only letters.")
    print("Contains only lower case letters.")
elif not words.isdigit() and words.islower() and words.endswith(".") and not numbers:
    print("Contains only letters.")
    print("Contains only lower case letters.")
    print("Ends with period.")
elif not words.isdigit() and words.isupper() and not words.endswith(".") and not numbers:
    print("Contains only letters.")
    print("Contains only upper letters.")
elif not words.isdigit() and words.isupper() and words.endswith(".") and not numbers:
    print("Contains only letters.")
    print("Contains only upper letters.")
    print("Ends with period.")
elif words.isdigit():
    print("Contains only digits.")```


  [1]: https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/
  [2]: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp
  [3]: https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/
````

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started:

```
lstupper = [chr(x) for x in range(65,90+1)]  # A-Z
lstlower = [chr(x) for x in range(97,122+1)]  # a-z
lstnums =  ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

lstletters = lstupper + lstlower
lstlettersandnums = lstupper + lstlower + lstnums

word = 'apple'

allletters  = True
allnums = True

for c in word:  # each letter in 'apple'
   if not c in lstnums:  # if character not in number list
       allnums = False  
   if not c in lstletters:  # if character not in letter list
       allletters = False
       
print(allnums, allletters)   # False True
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve this the problem:

```
words = input("Enter a Letter: ")
if words.isalpha():
    print("Contains only letters")
elif words.isupper():
    print("Contains only upper letters")
elif words.islower():
    print("Contains only lower letters")
elif words.isalnum():
    print("Contains only digits")
```